# Change title and meta description in included page (not template)

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to change title and meta description for pages used for products.
The goal is to have the same effect as here:
`<script>document.title = "<?php echo $new_title; ?>";</script>`

The page with lists of products is a template where are includes in some conditions.

template_listing.php:

```
if (!empty($offer['listingId']))
    include('include_offer.php');
```

I'm struggling with how to change title/description in include_offer.php.
My findings so far:

```
function wp1_filter_wp_title($title) {

if (is_page_template('include_offer.php')) {
    return 'some title';
}
return $title;
}
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'wp1_filter_wp_title');
```

But it doesn't work. It's working only if `if (is_page_template('template_listing.php'))`.
Is there any function like 'is_page_template' which also works for included pages?

Edit:

```
function show_template() {
global $template;
echo basename($template);
}
```

basename on that single product page return 'template_listing.php'

I also figured out there is function `get_included_files` but I'm not sure how to use that in my case.

Comment: Have you looked at the `$pagenow` global variable? Or the `get_current_screen`? Are you able to target a specific page based on the output URL?  If so, check here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_screen/

Comment: @TonyDjukic I doubt it can be useful here.

Comment: I've found a workaround [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13009592/14378765).
In header - ob_start(), in footer ob_end_flush().
I dont think its a good solution/good practice to use that. 
If I want to change meta description I have to use it as well :/